# Visual Studio 2013 method return value is very limiting

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Most of the blogs/tutorials I've seen regarding the new feature of VS 2013 that allows us to see the return value of a method from within the method use a console application and return only primitive types.

The MSDN article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx says

"*Note that if a function returns a struct, it will not be displayed in the Autos window with the exceptions of enums and structs that have exactly one field which is the size of a pointer (i.e. structs with the same characteristics as enums).*"

But it does not make things very clear.

I can't see the return value in a web application even in if I'm using static methods. So the below example that was used in the MSDN article will not work in a web application.

```
private static int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
{
  return (num1 * num2);
}
```

Also, the article does not explicitly mention about not showing return values for methods returning class instances. Is it assumed here that structs and classes fall under the same category?

Comment: To understand why the debugger has trouble display the return value, you first have to understand how processors work.  That's a long story.  What do you *really* want to know?  Isn't the web project misbehavior more relevant?  You can reports bugs at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: If you’d like to delete your question, you have the ability to do so.